# Pass more than one column through to group_modify

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to produce some weighted summary statistics, currently using `group_modify()`. For example, say I have this df:

```
require(tidyverse)

x <- tibble::tribble(
                 ~treatment,   ~question, ~bin, ~weight,
  "first_name_of_treatment",    "didyou",   1L,     5.6,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "didthey",   0L,    10.3,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "willyou",   1L,    45.1,
  "first_name_of_treatment",  "willthey",   0L,     2.2,
  "first_name_of_treatment", "didntthey",   1L,     1.5,
           "another_t_name",    "didyou",   0L,    93.4,
           "another_t_name",   "didthey",   NA,      NA,
           "another_t_name",   "willyou",   1L,    52.1,
           "another_t_name",  "willthey",   0L,     3.9,
           "another_t_name", "didntthey",   NA,      NA
  )
```

If I run the following code, I get the output that's shown below.

```
x %>% group_by(treatment, question) %>% 
    group_modify(~
                     tibble(
                         n = sum(!is.na(.x)), 
                         mean = round(mean(as.numeric(unlist(.x)), na.rm = T), digits = 2), 
                         sd = round(sd(as.numeric(unlist(.x)), na.rm = T), digits = 2), 
                         se = round(sd/sqrt(n), digits = 3), 
                         ci_lo = round(mean - qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se, digits = 3),  # qnorm() gets the specified Z-score
                         ci_hi = round(mean + qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se, digits = 3),
                         count_na = sum(is.na(.x))
                     )
    )
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 9
# Groups:   treatment, question [10]
   treatment               question     n   mean    sd     se   ci_lo  ci_hi count_na
   <chr>                   <chr>    <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
 1 another_t_name          didntth…     0 NaN    NA    NA     NaN     NaN           2
 2 another_t_name          didthey      0 NaN    NA    NA     NaN     NaN           2
 3 another_t_name          didyou       2  46.7  66.0  46.7   -44.8   138.          0
 4 another_t_name          willthey     2   1.95  2.76  1.95   -1.88    5.78        0
 5 another_t_name          willyou      2  26.6  36.1  25.5   -23.5    76.6         0
 6 first_name_of_treatment didntth…     2   1.25  0.35  0.247   0.766   1.73        0
 7 first_name_of_treatment didthey      2   5.15  7.28  5.15   -4.94   15.2         0
 8 first_name_of_treatment didyou       2   3.3   3.25  2.30   -1.20    7.80        0
 9 first_name_of_treatment willthey     2   1.1   1.56  1.10   -1.06    3.26        0
10 first_name_of_treatment willyou      2  23.0  31.2  22.0   -20.2    66.3         0
```

This is close to what I want, but the statistics in the grouped tibble are for the `weight` column, whereas what I want is for them to be for the `bin` column and apply the weights to that.

So the ideal outcome is: the weighted mean of the `bin` column from the original tibble, for each value of `treatment` and `question`, weighted by the `weight` column (probably using `weighted.mean`).

If I run `select(-weight)` before running `group_by(treatment, question)` I get the summary stats for the `bin` column (which is what I want), but then I don't have access to the weights which means I can't apply them.

Is it possible to do what I want with a combination of `weighted.mean` and `group_modify()`? If not, what is a better way I can do this?

Comment: I’m not sure if I totally follow but I think the ‘across()’ function should do that for you but I got confused by the bin and apply weights comment.  You can try including the weight in the grouping argument. Perform the transformations at the bin level and then apply the result to the weight column (if I understood correctly)

Comment: Thanks alejandro. I have edited that comment so hopefully it's clearer now. I tried including `weight` in the grouping argument, but this makes summary stats of `bin` for *each* value of `weight`, which is not what I want. What I want is to create summary stats of `bin` for each value of `treatment` and `question`, but applying the `weight` column to the summary stats (i.e. i want the weighted mean of `bin`, weighted by `weight`)

Comment: I guess if we focus on one output to make sure I understand - for example the `first_name_of_treatment` and `didyou` which you have bin of 0L and weight of 5.6. What are you expecting the SD for that entry to be? There is only one row? So wouldn't grouping by treatment and question when you only have one row produce NA? Sorry I'm just a bit confused into the initial calculations and at what grouping that should be applied to before we "weight" those outputs by the binning parameters

Comment: Ah I see the confusion; my bad. To clarify: `x` is just an example df. In my actual df I have thousands of instances of `question` for each value of `treatment` (and a few more instances of `treatment`). In the example, i've provided, yes, the value will be NA for that row. In my actual data it will not. I'm more interested in the mechanics of how I can pass through `weight` to `group_modify` so I can construct a weighted mean

Comment: got it, okay, I will add in some more sample data and provide a solution shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this just using `summarize` and `mutate`. It was actually much simpler than I realized!

```
x %>%
  group_by(treatment, question) %>%
  summarize(
    n = sum(!is.na(bin)),
    wt_mean = weighted.mean(bin, weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    wt_sd = Hmisc::wtd.var(bin, weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    wt_se = round(Hmisc::wtd.var(bin, weight, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(bin))), digits = 3), 
    count_na = sum(is.na(bin))
  ) %>%
  mutate(wt_ci_lo = round(wt_mean - qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * wt_se, digits = 3),  # qnorm() gets the specified Z-score
         wt_ci_hi = round(wt_mean + qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * wt_se, digits = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

require(tidyverse)
#updated your tibble with more data

```
x <- tibble::tribble(
                 ~treatment,   ~question, ~bin, ~weight,
  "first_name_of_treatment",    "didyou",   1L,     5.6,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "didthey",   0L,    10.3,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "willyou",   1L,    45.1,
  "first_name_of_treatment",  "willthey",   0L,     2.2,
  "first_name_of_treatment", "didntthey",   1L,     1.5,
  "first_name_of_treatment",    "didyou",   1L,     1.6,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "didthey",   0L,    4.3,
  "first_name_of_treatment",   "willyou",   1L,    70.1,
  "first_name_of_treatment",  "willthey",   0L,     5.2,
  "first_name_of_treatment", "didntthey",   1L,     7.5,
           "another_t_name",    "didyou",   0L,    93.4,
           "another_t_name",   "didthey",   NA,      NA,
           "another_t_name",   "willyou",   1L,    52.1,
           "another_t_name",  "willthey",   0L,     3.9,
           "another_t_name", "didntthey",   NA,      NA,
           "another_t_name",    "didyou",   0L,    30.4,
           "another_t_name",   "didthey",   NA,      NA,
           "another_t_name",   "willyou",   1L,    2.1,
           "another_t_name",  "willthey",   0L,     13.9,
           "another_t_name", "didntthey",   NA,      NA)
```

Then used summarize and across combined with mutate to do the calculations

```
x %>% 
  group_by(treatment,question,bin) %>% 
  summarize(
    across(weight,
         list( 
           n = ~sum(!is.na(.)),
           mean = ~round(mean(as.numeric(., na.rm = T), digits = 2)),
           sd = ~round(sd(as.numeric(.), na.rm = T), digits = 2),
           count_na = ~sum(is.na(.))
         ),.names = "{.fn}"
    ),.groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    se = round(sd/sqrt(n), digits = 3),
    ci_lo = round(mean - qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se, digits = 3),
    ci_hi =round(mean + qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se, digits = 3),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. This does what I expected though and creates summary stats across levels of weight, which is not what I need. I actually figured out how to do what I want just using `summarize` and `mutate` (will post an answer shortly). I really appreciate your help thinking this through! Thank you

Comment: okay! sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Not at all. You've been super helpful. Hope you have a nice day!